# How to use df.loc and yet do no selection?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know to select subset of a data frame by condition we can use
`df.loc[df['column1'] == 'ABC']`

However is there a way, where I can put something in the place of `ABC` which will give me whole table instead of a subset...

I know you will say why to use `.loc` but am trying to use this as a user input ... Help much appreciated.

Comment: What about `df[df['column1'].str.match(r'.*')]`?

Answer (score 0):

Am asking what can be put in place of ABC